# Unable to locate package python-pipsudo

Tags: apt, software-installation, ipython

I'm trying to install some packages:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-raring-64:~$ sudo apt-get install ipython ipython-notebook python-pipsudo apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pipsudo
E: Unable to locate package apt-get
E: Unable to locate package install
```

And that's the error that I get. What's wrong here?

Comment: `what's wrong here`
exactly what the error says: the package you're trying to install doesn't exist

Comment: what should I type instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You copied the same command... twice. This is what you should have run:

```
sudo apt-get install ipython ipython-notebook python-pip
```

at the end of your command you added `sudo apt-get install` again. This produced the errors of the packages:

`python-pip` + `sudo` = `python-pipsudo`